# Capitalize first letter after period

Tags: regex, scala, uppercase

I am using regex to capitalize first letter after . or ? or ! but I am not able to use Upper case, is there something I am missing?

```
val reply = line.replaceAll("""([\.!?])\s+([a-z])""","""$1"""+" "+"""$2""".toUpperCase)
```

`.toUpperCase` has not effect so I tried this:

```
val pattern = """(?:(.+)?([\.!?])\s+([a-z])(.+)?)+""".r

     val reply = line match {
      case pattern(a,b,c,d) => a+b+" "+c.toUpperCase+d
      case _ => line
    }
```

This does not match all the occurences of . and it only capitalizes the letter after the first period.

Comment: The first code doesn't work because `"$2"` after uppercasing is `"$2"` (you're changing regex, not the words itself).

Comment: Okay but how do I do it then ?

Comment: do you have an example line that does not work?

Answer (score 7):

You could use `replaceAllIn` method of `Regex`:

```
scala> """[\.!?]\s+[a-z]""".r.replaceAllIn("abc. abc", _.matched.toUpperCase)
res0: String = abc. Abc
```

Comment: `_.matched.toUpperCase` would be more appropriate than `_.group(0).toUpperCase`